# Error C2065 when using two MFC projects

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a Dialog with a `CListCtrl` with some data, below is a button. My second project is a dialog with a tri-state checkbox. Now I want to couple both projects, so when selecting a list item and clicking the button the tristate dialog appers showing something.

Well, I added the second project to another one and changed its type to .dll, but receive a build error

`error C2065: 'IDD_MFCAPP2_DIALOG' : undeclared identifier`

`IDD_MFCAPP2_DIALOG` is the id of he checkbox dialog. When adding the project both id's had the same value, so I changed this in `resource.h` manually to a different one, but it did not solve the problem. The projects work very well separately. What do I miss?

UPDATE:
I have reduced the project to a minimum, the problem is the same

**MFCApp1Dlg.h**

```
class CMFCApp1Dlg : public CDialogEx
{
// Construction
public:
    CMFCApp1Dlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);  // standard constructor

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_MFCAPP1_DIALOG };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support


// Implementation
protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;

    // Generated message map functions
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
  afx_msg void OnBnClickedButtonChange();
  CButton m_BtnChange;
};
```

Its cpp file only contains the standard things. Just the button handler calls other app

```
void CMFCApp1Dlg::OnBnClickedButtonChange()
{
 CMFCApp2Dlg dlg;
 if (dlg.DoModal())
 {
    // do something...
  }
}
```

**MFCApp2Dlg.h** looks the same

```
class CMFCApp2Dlg : public CDialogEx
{
// Construction
public:
    CMFCApp2Dlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);  // standard constructor

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_MFCAPP2_DIALOG };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support


// Implementation
protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;

    // Generated message map functions
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

The .rc file are also not spectaculary

```
IDD_MFCAPP1_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 315, 151
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION "MFCApp1"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,76,119,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,157,117,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Push me!",IDC_BUTTON_CHANGE,121,44,50,14
END
```

and

```
IDD_MFCAPP2_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 203, 101
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION "MFCApp2"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,46,64,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,109,65,50,14
    CONTROL         "Check1",IDC_CHECK1,"Button",BS_AUTO3STATE | WS_TABSTOP,51,17,39,10
    CONTROL         "Check2",IDC_CHECK2,"Button",BS_AUTO3STATE | WS_TABSTOP,51,39,39,10
END
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

UPDATE2:

```
Resource.h of App1
#define IDD_MFCAPP1_DIALOG              102
#define IDR_MAINFRAME                   128
#define IDC_BUTTON_CHANGE               1000

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        129
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         32771
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1001
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

and Resource.h of App2 respectively

```
#define IDD_MFCAPP2_DIALOG              202
#define IDR_MAINFRAME                   228
#define IDC_CHECK1                      2000
#define IDC_CHECK2                      2001

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        229
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         32771
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         2002
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           201
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: without seeing any code (ideally an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) it's near impossible to tell you what goes wrong.

Comment: If that `IDD_MFCTRISTATECHECKBOX_DIALOG` is supposed to be used somewhere, then why does it show up in neither shown .rc nor your .h files?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's just a new solution. I mean `IDD_MFCAPP2_DIALOG`, of course

Comment: where is that defined? there should be header file defining the constant? usually something like xyzRes.h - maybe you are missing that file?

Comment: they are there. Otherwise the projects would not build at all.

Comment: so those .h files for the resource defines both have the same name? Maybe the one is including the wrong one?

Answer (score 0):

The message just tells you that the ID is an unknown identifier. So just not known. So usually:

Make sure that you included the correct resource.h file AND make sure that the ID is defined in the resource.h

Comment: Both ID's are defined, of course. Moreover I changed included resource path to ".\resource.h", without success...

Comment: Use the /showincludes Option to see, if the resource.h file is really included. And which one. Are you sure you placed the include AFTER the stdafx.h include?